# How to typeset data structures with algorithm2e?

Tags: algorithm2e, data-structures

The question [How to typeset data structures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31328/how-to-typeset-data-structures) gives create answers for how to type set simple data structures with the `lstlistings` package. In particular, I like the following look (taken from Mico's answer):

[image: nicely typeset struct]

However, I am using the `algorithm2e` package to typeset algorithms and pseudo-code. How do I best typeset a simple data structure like the above with `algorithm2e`?

Comment: Will the strings "struct" and "float" be constant?

Comment: For now, I only need to typeset one such `struct`, so they can be. A more generic solution would be cool, though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a `\Struct` that matches one of the existing structures within the [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) framework. In this case, it resembles a **repeat** ... **until**, so I'd use `\SetKwRepeat{Struct}{struct \{}{\}}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[noline]{algorithm2e}

\SetKwRepeat{Struct}{struct \{}{\}}%
\newcommand{\Float}{\KwSty{float}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetAlgoNoLine\PrintSemicolon
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
  initialization\;
  \Struct{Vec}{
    \Float{} x,y,z\; 
  }
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      go to next section\;
      current section becomes this one\;
    }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
  }
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Many other adjustments (in terms of fonts, for example) are possible.